# How to open 3G Service screen programmatically? Android

Tags: android

Settings > communications(tab) > wireless & networks > Mobile Networks >3G service...I have seen an application which does this..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.Settings");
startActivity(intent);
```

this code opens up until `Mobile Networks`..

Specifically i wan to open up `3G Service` in Mobile Networks..

Comment: On my phone there is no such menu as `3G Service` (GT-i9001).

Comment: which version of android is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no documented and supported way to do this, and any undocumented/unsupported means will not be reliable. Few Android devices have a "communications(tab)" entry in Settings, few have a "3G service" entry in Settings, etc.